# Reveal JavaScript decryption algorithm

Tags: javascript, encryption, developer-tools

I have been trying to understand how exchange rates are updated real-time on this [website.](https://www1.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/) With a quick look at the 'network' tab on developer tools, it became clear that website is getting responses periodically from this [url.](https://www.oanda.com/lfr/rates_lrrr?tstamp=1563520650717) The problem is that the response text from the requests consist of sequences of random letters and numbers. It seems that actual content is encrypted and since exchange rates are displayed on client side, response data should be somehow decrypted with JavaScript on front end (I think).

So, my question is, what are some hints to explore JavaScript decryption algorithm, since all 'js' files are minified and variable names are just letters? What kind of tools and practices could you use to solve this kind problems?

Any suggestion or help on this matter would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code (not minfied) can be seen [here](https://www1.oanda.com/jslib/wl/lrrr/liverates.js). You will notice that it uses a function `rc4decrypt` to decrypt the data. `rc4decrypt` is defined as:

```
function rc4decrypt (a){
  return rc4(key,hexDecode(a))
};
```

where `key` is a global (`window`) variable. Further steps should be easy.

(Please be aware of any legal implications of your actions).

Comment: I am now able to decrypt the response text. Thank you for your help!

Comment: P.S. I am doing it just for curiosity.